# Assistance with some MongoDB queries

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this item structure (C#):

```
event2 = new EventItem
                {
                    type = "Warning",
                    date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(i * (-1.5)),//in a seed loop
                    serverGroupId = "507f1f77bcf86cd799439012",
                    serverLocalId = "507f1f77bcf86cd799429015",
                    system = "Authentication server",
                    message = "User has logged in from another IP.",
                    messageAttributes = new AttributeItem[] { new AttributeItem { param = "userId", value = "789efe77bcf86cd799439013" },
                                                                new AttributeItem { param = "component", value = "server" }},
                    warningLevel = 4
                };
```

I want to find the most frequent component that a log is about, which has occurred in the last 24 hours and is of type warning or error. So far I have written the query that gives me all logs within 24 hours that are of type error or warning, but I am having trouble with the part with the most frequent component:

```
var results = collection.Find(Query.And
                (
                    Query.Or
                    (
                        Query.EQ("type", "Warning"),
                        Query.EQ("type", "Error")
                    ),
                    Query.GT("date", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)),
                    Query.LT("date", DateTime.Now)
                )
            );
```

What do I need to add to get the most frequent component (and possibly the number of logs with that component within the last 24 hours)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either the mongodb map/reduce or group/reduce query family, or better yet the aggregation framework.

Have a look at this page for examples in C# :
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mongodb-aggregation-framework